# Is there a way to draw a graph (vertices & edges) in LaTeX on this website?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, images

I googled and found how to do it in LaTeX software on your computer, but what about this website, possible to draw graphs as easy as writing out a matrix in LaTeX?

Failing that is there some website that will generate an image for you given the graph spec.

Thanks.

Comment: No, I do not think so. Instead, you need to draw your graphs in LaTeX, save the picture (using a screenshot, say) and then upload that to here.

Comment: Related: [What software is used to draw undirected graphs?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31626/what-software-is-used-to-draw-undirected-graphs) and [Graph theory software?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58973/graph-theory-software)

Comment: (And for the record, use TikZ if you want to draw anything in $\LaTeX$. And I mean *anything*. Well, anything *mathematical*.)

Comment: If I thought there was even a remote chance that it would be satisfied, my number one feature-request would be tikz support for MSE.

Comment: @Alexander. I'd second that, since I use tikz for all the pictures I've posted (and lots of handouts for my classes), but you'd probably agree that tikz has a frightfully steep learning curve for novices.

Comment: Also this post on meta discusses creating and posting various kinds of diagrams on this site: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9632/creating-diagrams (And you can find links to more such posts there.)

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31963/26327

Comment: There is now: https://q.uiver.app/

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know I made this post :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there are *many* ways to create a picture, and upload it here. Some of the more obvious alternatives are:

(1) MS Paint, GIMP, or other paint programs

(2) Illustrator, Corel, Powerpoint, Inkscape, or other vector drawing packages

(3) TikZ or MetaPost or Asymptote, if you think that writing code is a good way to create pictures.

(4) Mathematica, Maple, Matlab, or any other package with graphing capabilities

(5) Draw on paper, and scan

(6) Draw on a whiteboard (or even a blackboard), and shoot with a camera or mobile phone.

Options 5 and 6 give you a bitmap image directly. The other options will require you to generate one indirectly. A screen grab is usually the easiest way.

For graphs, I would recommend #2 or #5, personally.

Comment: Please, don't use a point-and shoot camera or phone camera unless you're photographing something three-dimensional.

Comment: @defeuer -- why is that?

Comment: Because it produces images that tend to be even harder to read than proper scans of the same hand-scribbled notes.

Comment: I personally like the draw on paper and scan the most and this will become more and more accessible until that's all we use.

Comment: You forgot to mention PSTricks.

Answer (score 14):

If you know *Mathematica* syntax you can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Graph%5B%7B1%20%5C%5BUndirectedEdge%5D%202,%202%20%5C%5BUndirectedEdge%5D%203,%20%20%20%203%20%5C%5BUndirectedEdge%5D%201,%202%20%5C%5BUndirectedEdge%5D%202%7D%5D) for simple graphs. Then post the image here:

[image: graphs]

Answer (score 5):

Graphviz can draw graphs, and google charts API can do graphviz. See [erdos](http://sandbox.kidstrythisathome.com/erdos/) for a tool that lets you use the API interactively.

Alternatively, you can use tikz, and a site like [writelatex.com](https://www.writelatex.com/) to render it.

When using either of these, I use imgur.com's [browser plugin](https://imgur.com/apps) to rehost the image, and I use [gist](https://gist.github.com/) to save the source; I make sure to link the sources from my diagrams in my questions and answers.

Typically, I use <sup><\sup> to "caption" the images from underneath.

Another trick: when displaying multiple images, you can resize them to fit on the same row side-by-side; IIRC the width of the display is ~660 pixels (on at least on cs.SE; I hope it doesn't change!) - image hosting sites like imgur.com directly support simple image editing, like scaling and cropping - then I caption them underneath like "left: description, right: description".

Example:

> [image: Image of graph]
>     [image: Image of shortest path]
>     [image: Image of non intersecting shortest path]
>
> <sup><sup>Left: [Full graph](https://www.writelatex.com/read/jzkhmqgmqcnj). Center: [shortest path](https://www.writelatex.com/read/kwpwzzcfyjcy). Right: [shortest non-intersecting path](https://www.writelatex.com/read/qzrbvwxgpbtp).</sup></sup>

Comment: Oh, please don't rely on a certain number of pixels in the display!

Comment: You can put images side-by-side in $\LaTeX$ using `\minipage`

Comment: @dfeuer you can combine the images if need be lol. Or like user1729 suggested, you can combine them in LaTeX.

Comment: @RealzSlaw: "This image you are requesting does not exist or no longer available".

Comment: @Moron true, but it doesn't really matter what the image is, the point is the captions. If it bothers you, you can edit in any image .

Comment: the images no longer exist, can you lease edit that$

Comment: @user153330 done